# Export Excel from web, what's the BEST way?

Tags: asp.net, excel

About 3 years ago, I was looking for a way to allow a web app user to download table results to an Excel file. I knew that I didn't want to put Office on the web server and that I probably wanted to create the XLS file in XML format. The question was: what was the best way?

Now I am writing my resume and I am trying to recap the things that I did and I am concerned that I didn't take the best approach and I am wondering if somebody can tell me whether my suspicions are true.

Basically, I saved an Excel file as XML and then looked at the contents of the saved file and reverse engineered what I thought was a pretty cool SDK to create an Excel file in XML format. It was fairly robust with options , nice object model, etc.

But did such a library already exist? One that I could have used? I want to know if I will need to defend this "accomplishment"

Also, could anyone recommend me a good place where I can see actual resumes of people with .NET / SQL Server or general developer skills?

Comment: I think the programming skills that took will be what's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [SmartXLS](http://www.smartxls.com) (for Java or .Net), it supports most features of Excel (cell formatting, Charts, formulas, pivot tables etc), and can read/write both the Excel97-2003 xls format and the Excel2007 openxml format.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No one (so far) has identified a "Microsoft-way" to produce an XML Excel file, so I will assume from this and the existing abundance of 3rd party components for this purpose that there probably is not such a component. Both answers voted up. ty!

Comment: @liya: I undeleted any of your SmartXLS answers that had been upvoted or accepted.  Please disclose your affiliation with SmartXLS, as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Answer (score 2):

[These people](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/) wrote a perfectly good one that you probably couldn't implement yourself for as cheaply.

Comment: I agree. I saw some, but my company was opposed to purchasing a 3rd party component. If is was MS and free, I could have used it, else not. I suspect that Micrososft might have had a way, usually they are pretty good at that kind of stuff, but I couldn't find one in the time I gave myself.